# On 1-1 correspondence and equivalence relation

Tags: real-analysis, equivalence-relations

[image]Can someone please explain to me why a 1-1 correspondence between $A$ and $B$ is "clearly" an equivalence relation.

Thanks for your help.

I got this from the rudin's principle of mathematical analysis.

Comment: At least can you see reflexivity? I mean, what is the most obvious map from a space to itself which is $1-1$ and onto?

Comment: Are you pertaining to an identity map?

Comment: This notation is definitely different from how I was taught. Instead of the notation $A\sim B$, I use $A\leftrightarrow B$.

Comment: Precisely, Newton. Now, for symmetry, if there is a one-one onto map from $A$ to $B$, then why can you "reverse" this map, to get a map from $B$ to $A$? And yes, $+1$.

Comment: It is an equivalence relation because if the sets $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinal number, they are *equivalent* sets. Since both these sets are equivalent, then the relation of how $A$ and $B$ are equivalent sets would "clearly" be known as an *equivalence relation*.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Let me just ask, is the relation a subset of $A×B$?

Comment: Let $X=\{A, B, ...\}$. Then the relation is a subset of $X \times X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two sets will be in a one-to-one relation *if and only if* they have the same cardinality.  $$\{(A,B)\mid\exists f~ (f: A\overset{1:1}\mapsto B)\}=\{(A,B)\mid A\equiv B\}$$

It is *clear* that every set has the same cardinality as itself.   That's reflexivity. $$\forall A~(A\equiv A)$$

Take any two sets.   If the first set has the same cardinality as the second set, then it is *clear* that second set has the same cardinality as the first.   That's symmetry.$$\forall A\forall B~(A\equiv B\to B\equiv A)$$

Take any three sets.   If the first has the same cardinality as the second, and the second the same cardinality as the third, then it is *clear* that the first will have the same cardinality as the third.   That's transitivity.$$\forall A\forall B\forall C~((A\equiv B)\wedge (B\equiv A)\to (A\equiv C))$$

So $\{(A,B)\mid\exists f~ (f: A\overset{1:1}\mapsto B)\}$ is clearly an equivalence relation.

Comment: Are $A$, $B$, and $C$ members of the same set?

Comment: They *are* sets.

Answer (score 0):

The relation is not the same as the bijective function. The definition of the relation is that A~B if there is a bijective function $f:A\to B$. From that definition it is fairly obvious that ~ becomes an equivalence relation on any given set of sets, just using the properties of bijective functions. Namely, that the identity on any set is a bijection, that the inverse of a bijection is a bijection and that the composite of two bijections is again a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

The relation $\sim$ is an equivalence relation because for any sets $A, B$ and $C$:

$(1)$ There exists a $1-1$ mapping of $A$ onto $A$.

$(2)$ If there exists a $1-1$ mapping of $A$ onto $B$, then there exists a $1-1$ mapping of $B$ onto $A$.

$(3)$ If there exists a $1-1$ mapping of $A$ onto $B$, and there exists a $1-1$ mapping of $B$ onto $C$, then there exists a $1-1$ mapping of $A$ onto $C$.